# Code is "partially crashing" when trying to create HSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, jar, dependencies, apache-poi, executable

I will try to make this as detailed as possible as I need help figuring this out and it is the last step in my project .I am extremely close to the completed development of a desktop application I made for use in industry. The app reads an inputted .xls file and uses data from there to populate an empty form sheet. On my desk computer, the program is perfect and works from the desktop icon as it should (Being run as a shortcut to an executable .jar file). Here is the Main class in the .jar.

```
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Launcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        ExcelReader reader = new ExcelReader();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "starting reader");
        reader.main(args);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "starting writer");
        ExcelWriter writer = new ExcelWriter(reader);
        writer.main(args);
    }
}
```

However, when running the same .jar file on another computer, it reaches a point in the reader where it is to take the selected File, turn it into an InputStream, and then turn it into an HSSFWorkbook. I have JOptionPanes the display progress of the code in my reader, and it is making it right up until the line where the workbook is to be created.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
    final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);

    if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        file = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("File Selected for Input: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File chosen : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File has been selected");
    //Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
    //desktop.open(file);
    try {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Making inputstream");
        InputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(file);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "making workbook with " + excelFile.toString());
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "making sheet");
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "sheet made 8)");
```

Once I can figure out as to why running it on a different computer is causing problems, I can very easily finish up my app. I am using Apache POI documentation will attach my file paths [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgcfv.jpg). Any help is GREATLY appreciated. I suspect the issue may be with my .jar structure, but I cannot find any issues with that either. I have attached my Jar Structure [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35pVv.jpg). I am more than happy to attach, discuss, or include information of any questions needed. Very eager to get this finished!

Comment: What error message do you get? Is there any stack trace?

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy I am only recveiving the error when I use the executable jar. Is there a way to receive a stack trace from that?